# Ajax request sent via GET even if method is POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax-request

I have ran in to this strange bug in my production environment. I had several AJAX requests in my Ruby on Rails application with GET methods, now I decided to change this security error holes. I changed most of the requests to POST. Everything works just fine in local environment and in demo environment, which is almost the same as the production environment.

Request: (CoffeeScript)

```
$(".vehicle_make_dropdown").on "change", ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/get_maker_models"
      data:
        maker: $("#entry_vehicle_make").val()
      method: "POST" // this was "GET" before!
      dataType: "JSON"
    ).success( (json) ->
      i = 0
      $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").html("")
      $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").prop("disabled", false)
      while(i < json.length)
        $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").append("<option value='#{json[i]["title"]}'>#{json[i]['title']}</option>")
        i++
    ).error( (resp) ->
      console.log("error")
    )
```

Reciever: (Ruby (RoR))

```
def get_maker_models
  @models = VehicleMaker.find_by(title: params[:maker]).vehicle_models.order("title ASC")
  render json: @models
end
```

Route:

```
post "get_maker_models" => 'credit_form#get_maker_models'
```

but in logs i still se this:

```
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.852487 #28300]  INFO -- : Started GET "/get_maker_models/" for 80.232.253.212 at 2014-09-18 14:08:47 +0400
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.856224 #28300]  INFO -- : Processing by ApplicationController#routing_error as JSON
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.856329 #28300]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"path"=>"get_maker_models"}
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.863482 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered error/404.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.868535 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_audit_start.html.haml (1.1ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.882499 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_main_menu.html.haml (1.5ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.882696 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_header.html.haml (11.7ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.902478 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_mini_faq.html.haml (8.9ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.907767 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_main_menu.html.haml (0.4ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.914008 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_scripts.html.erb (1.1ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.914220 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_footer.html.haml (29.0ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.917616 #28300]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/shared/_audit_end.html.haml (0.9ms)
I, [2014-09-18T14:08:47.917902 #28300]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 61ms (Views: 55.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

I have tried:

- Deploying older version and than again the current one
- Restarting unicorn few times. Nothing seems to work,
- Tried Incognito mode in Chrome.
- Recompiled assets with production environmtt.

  EDIT:

In ajax request i changed method to type

Comment: Use either `$.post(URL,data,callback);` or specify `type` in your ajax request. Should solve your problem.

Comment: i changed to type same results

Comment: Well, im not sure if changing to production environment could make such problems. But what I suspect is `caching` which usually is enabled in the production environments. If this is included in the page and the cache is not bursted then this could be the cause of the problem. Im just giving my thoughts :)

Comment: @user2945241 look at this answer http://goo.gl/noXv1e , hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

When rebuilding assets, did you specify environment? As `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

EDIT:

$.ajax Should have `type` for specifying type of the request instead of `method`.
The default is GET, so probably that is the issue here.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check whether that solves the problem.