# Alternative method for not allowing GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, get, routes

Hello what would be alternative method to not allow GET requests from browser.

This is related question: [Ajax request sent via GET even if method is POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910632/ajax-request-sent-via-get-even-if-method-is-post)

I have this ajax requests:

```
$(".vehicle_make_dropdown").on "change", ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/get_maker_models"
      data:
        maker: $("#entry_vehicle_make").val()
      type: "GET"
      dataType: "JSON"
    ).success( (json) ->
      i = 0
      $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").html("")
      $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").prop("disabled", false)
      while(i < json.length)
        $(".vehicle_model_dropdown").append("<option value='#{json[i]["title"]}'>#{json[i]['title']}</option>")
        i++
    ).error( (resp) ->
      console.log("error")
    )
```

and this route:

```
get "get_maker_models" => 'credit_form#get_maker_models'
```

How could i allow only this to be ajax request, so it is not accessible via browser url. I mean so there would not be an routing error when i try to access get_maker_models trough browser via GET?

EDIT:

Alternative:

- `request.xhr?`
- `match "get_maker_models" => 'credit_form#get_maker_models', via: [:get, :post], constraints: -> (req) { req.xhr? }`

Any other alternatives?

Comment: Check `request.xhr?` and abort if not ajax

Comment: okey i understand that, but are there any way more raily that does not feel like a litte hack, i dont wish to put this condition before every method that is called by ajax.

Comment: http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/routing-only-ajax-requests-in-ror/

There's a recipe there on how to constrain routes